# is it safe to delete adat files when clearing up space in Mac?

Tags: disk-space

Adat files are taking a lot of space in my Mac hard disk. They are in "Other" folder. Apparently are an application file.
I read that there are some application's files that are created when using the app and can be deleted afterwards, but not sure if these can be cleared. Just called out my attention that are taking a huge amount of space.

[image: adat file location and size]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What are these files and where are they located?

Comment: Can you show the whole window with one file selected? The location of a selected file should be at the bottom.